# how can i use buttons or any user Input view on viewpager?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

Basically i have three buttons on viewpager's page 1 . and i want to select one of them and get the value into my db. but when i am clicking on any of the button it is showing me an error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.itsandpro.Signup.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:88)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)

and my code for button at viewpager is:

myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);

```
    weightloss=findViewById(R.id.reduceweight);
    maintainweight=findViewById(R.id.controlthecalories);
    gainweight=findViewById(R.id.goodphysique);

    weightloss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"it worked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
```

what i need is to select the button but i am unable to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `reference at com.example.itsandpro.Signup.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:88)` you set your OnClickListener in your Activity which is not noticeable in your pasted code.

When you're using a ViewPager you are also using Fragments.

Activity

- ViewPager

  - Fragment 1
  - Fragment 2
  - Fragment 3

If you want to add a click listener of a button which is on Fragment 1 (`Basically i have three buttons on viewpager's page 1`) you have to **register the click Listener in your Fragment** and not in your Activity **because the layout of your activity don't contain this buttons.**

If i'm wrong, please update your question with the code of your activity, the layout of your activity and the code of your first fragment plus viewpager.